# na.strings = c() in R

Tags: r, na

I am new to R and started exploring `na.strings = c()` function along with `read.csv`.

I have read that using this option, all the missing values will be replaced to NA but I don’t see that happening in my files. I don’t see any difference in the output despite using `na.strings = c()`. Please help if I am missing something. In both the cases, I see NA when *numeric* value is missing but not when *char* value is missing. So, what is the use of using this function?

Here is my sample csv file:

```
Char,Numeric
A,3
B, 
 ,5
```

And my code:

```
DF_withoutNA = read.csv("filepath/R_NA.csv",header = TRUE)
DF_with = read.csv("filepath /R_NA.csv",header = TRUE,
                   na.strings = c("Char","Numeric"))
head(DF_withoutNA)
  Char Numeric
1    A       3
2    B      NA
3            5
head(DF_with)
  Char Numeric
1    A       3
2    B      NA
3            5
```

Answer (score 6):

The `na.strings` argument is for substitution within the body of the file, that is, matching strings that should be replaced with `NA`.  So with your example if you pass the empty string `""` it should match your missing character string, which is stripped white space.

```
x <- read.csv("filepath/R_NA.csv",header=TRUE,na.strings=c(""))
x
 Char Numeric
1    A       3
2    B      NA
3 <NA>       5
```

Comment: `c("")` is the same as `""`, and `header=TRUE` is the default in `read.csv()`.

Answer (score 4):

> what is the use of using this function?

It replaces values (eg., characters, numbers) in you csv file with `NA`. If you try `read.csv("filepath/R_NA.csv", na.strings = "A")` you'll see that all `A`'s in csv were replaced with `NA`'s.

PS. `na.strings` is the argument, not the function.

Answer (score -1):

na.string replaces the missing values with 'NA' as a notation. This needs to be done preferably at the beginning of the data cleaning process.