# read.csv... na.strings very basic question

Tags: r, csv, filtering, na, read.csv

I'm a total newbie at R. I have a question concerning the reading csv discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765944/na-strings-c-in-r/71039065#71039065).

If you have a file that you have read in R Studio like that, with `na.strings=c("")`, and have thrown out every row containing NA w/ `na.omit()`, so that `anyNA()` renders FALSE, then wrote another csv (to process other stuff on Excel)... and now you are reading it back on RStudio... do you need `na.strings=c("")` again? ... I mean as an argument within read.csv()... (to keep having a file without empty cells)?

Comment: Don't know if I follow what you're asking, but why wouldn't you do that if you're concerned that new `NA` were introduced in the roundtrip with Excel? Also, you may want to check out `read_csv` from the `readr` package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374887/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-read-csv-and-read-csv-when-should-one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.